# I do not get contentDocument from iframe using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I need to get the page rendered with pdf.js.
From the view I insert the viewer.html into an iframe and try to get its contentDocument.

```
var direccion = '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+doc[xid].relativepathfile + doc[xid].adjnombre;
html = '<iframe src = "<?php echo base_url() ?>vendors/pdf/web/viewer.html?file='+direccion+'" width="100%" id = "fraViewDocumentsPDFViewer" runat = "server" height="100%"> </iframe>';
$("#superior").append(html);
iFrame =  document.getElementById('fraViewDocumentsPDFViewer');
console.log(iFrame.contentDocument);
```

The variable iFrame is global.
The result of `console.log(iFrame.contentDocument);` is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

if I run `iFrame.contentDocument` from the Chrome console, it shows me the correct content, I do not understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?